# Cannot create new Product with custom visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, insert, product

I have a custom visualforce page that has the Product2 standard controller and a class as extension. The objective here is to make it possible to enter the product information, and the user can click "Save and New", and the page will reload after inserting a new product with the informations that were typed in.

The issue I'm having right now is that even though I get all the fields from the visualforce page using the `inputField` markup, Salesforce keeps throwing me an error saying that a required field is missing. However this field is set (I can even check it being set using System.debug on the object, just right before the insertion).

Since I can check that the object has all the necessary fields using the debug feature, I would like to know if I'm missing something here, or if this is a bug?

The code is as follows:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" standardController="Product2" extensions="CadastroProdutosController">
<!-- Name: CriaMultiplosProdutos -->
    <apex:pageMessages/>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Novo Produto" collapsible="false" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!prod.ProductCode}" label="Código do Produto" required="true"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!prod.Fabricante__c}" label="Fabricante" required="true"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!prod.Modelo_do_produto__c}" label="Modelo do Produto"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!prod.Description}" label="Descrição" required="true"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!prod.regimeEspecial__c}" label="Regime Especial"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!prod.Family}" label="Família de Produtos" required="true"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!prod.Observacao__c}" label="Observação"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!prod.Ativo__c}" label="Ativo"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!prod.Fabricante_Codigo_do_produto__c}" label="Fabricante + Código do Produto"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!mySave}" value="Salvar"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And the controller:

```
public with sharing class CadastroProdutosController
{
    public ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    public Product2 prod {get;set;}

    public CadastroProdutosController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
    {
        this.controller = stdController;
        this.prod = new Product2();
    }

    public PageReference mySave()
    {
        try
        {
            System.debug(this.prod);
            insert this.prod;
            return new PageReference('/apex/CriaMultiplosProdutos');
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getCause() + ' ' + e.getMessage() + ', Line: ' + e.getLineNumber()));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are obviously missing something or it would work. However, without seeing your code it is impossible to say.

Comment: Edited my question with the code. Please, take a look.

Comment: Do you have workflow rules or triggers involved? It's possible that while the field is set right before insertion, some transaction logic might be wiping out the data. I strongly suspect your issue lies further down the transaction lifecycle than what you imagine.

Comment: There is an 'after insert' trigger on Product2 object, but since it is running after the record is inserted, it is definitely not the cause of the problem. I also checked the workflow rules but didn't see anything changing the name or code of the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put your code into my sandbox and I got the following error:

> Required fields are missing: [Product Name]

So you are missing the *name* **not** the *product code*

Adding the following and it works correctly:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!prod.Name}"  required="true"/>
```

Comment: That was it. It was a simple interpretation problem. Thank you Eric! I was so focused on the functionality that mistake the product's *code* for its *name* field in the code.

Comment: No worries.....as you can see via the thread, we ALL get focused on the wrong issue at times (Especially me) .